# HTC One display problem

Tags: screen, htc-one-x, terminal, screen-brightness

I've bought this HTC One from one guy who had to change the display on it. It works fine but display has  one problem. It has very high brightness and some buttons, icons and so on does not have the edges visible.

I tried to download some applications to lower the brightness but I haven't found one that worked perfectly. Some of these applications lowered the brightness and the situation got a little better but I couldn't set the brightness low enough with them.

I would like to ask if there is some way how to set the brightness or contrast manually via terminal in the operating system or this problem is more likely caused by bad display. Thanks very much for your answers (P.S.: I tried several Android ROMs, but no change occured).

Here is a photo of the display how it looks like (e.g. the black color is not black but silver. There are almost no visible circles around the ticks on the right side):

[image: Photo of the screen (click for larger variant)]
<sup>Photo of the screen (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: What about the built-in brightness settings? Maybe some automatic is still in effect? I don't have a HTC One, but I know some devices to automatic brightness adjustments, and some let you set a "base value" in combination; so maybe that's what's happening to you?

Comment: Which apps have you used to lower the brightness? The one I use on my S3 is [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor), which can lower the brightness to near invisibility on most screens.